# Finding number of invertible matrices in finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

First, Let me define a **finite** field $\mathbb Z_p $ (p is prime) with the following addition and multiplication:
$\ a,b \in \Bbb Z \\$ \ $\ a + b = $ remainder of $\ a +b $ when diving them by $\ p$

$\ a \times b = $ remainder of multiplication when dividing by $\ p $

Basically same as GF(2) field but with different number.

Let $\ \mathbf M_{2 \times 2} (\mathbb Z_p) $ group of matrices and I need to find the number of invertible matrices in that group.

I was thinking maybe to try and find under what conditions the determinant is zero but I couldn't figure it out on my own.

Comment: try taking a nonzero vector as first column  and try all the posibilities for the second column which are linearly independent to first, proceed inductively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

the first row has to be a non-zero vector in $\mathbf F_p^2$, which makes $p^2-1$ possibilities.

This vector being chosen, the second row is another vector which must be non-collinear to the first, which eliminates its $p$ scalar multiples (these include the zero vector).

**Note**:

Following the same lines, you can show the number of invertible $n\times n$-matrices in $\mathbf F_p$ is
$$ \bigl|\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbf F_p)\bigr|=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(p^n-p^{i}).$$

Comment: ok so our number of options for the second vector will be $\ p^2-p $ . and then calculating the number of possibilites for invertible matrices I get the same number as in the formula you gave me here. but just to make sure I understand correctly, we don't want linearly dependent second vector because then it means our matrice is equal to a matrice with zero vector and then it isn't invertible, am I correct? Sorry for long post it is just a bit hard for me to grasp.

Comment: Yes, you're perfectly correct. To make sure you grasp all details, try to prove the general formula.