# Probability of random $n \times n$ matrix in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ being invertible?

Tags: matrices, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am writing a program that uses the index calculus method for solving the DLP over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (where $p=2q+1$ for $q$ a prime). This involves choosing a set $\Gamma$ to be the first $n$ primes, and constructing a $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_q$. The problem is, depending on the size of $\Gamma$, this often does not have full rank, and so we choose more equations than unknowns in order to "guarantee" a full rank reduction after gaussian elimination (we only choose the first n rows after reduction). I want to know what the likelihood is for these matrices to be invertible, and if possible, how many extra equations for a given size of $\Gamma$ makes sure the likelihood is, say, over 90%? I've been working with $|\Gamma|/3$ with varying degrees of success.

Comment: Please clarify: does the matrix have entries in $\Bbb Z_p$ or $\Bbb Z_q$? Since you're asking about probability, how are you selecting the entries of the matrices?

Comment: Entries of the matrix are in $\mathbb{Z}_q$, as they represent equations in the exponent of a generator $g$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. What is done is, the generator $g$ is taken to increasing powers, and whenever $g^i$ can be factored as a product of primes in $\Gamma$, the "linear combination" of elements in gamma in it's exponent is equated to $i$ mod $2q$. Then these equations are solved mod $q$, and a correction is made in the case that the solution doesn't work mod $2q$ by simply adding $q$. I am beginning to suspect this is not uniformly random.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your entries are being chosen uniformly at random, note first that there are $q^{n^2}$ total matrices over $\mathbb F_q$, and according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788839/finding-number-of-invertible-matrices-in-finite-field) there are
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (q^n - q^i)$$
total matrices in $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$. Thus your desired probability is
$$q^{-n^2}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (q^n - q^i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-q^{-i}).$$